# Getting try-it proxy error due to two send mediator in In-Sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

My Code:

```
<filter xpath="get-property('statusFromClassMed')='Valid'">
                              <then>
                                 <log level="custom">
                                    <property name="InsideValidFilter" value="--------State is Valid-------"/>
                                 </log>
                                 <log level="custom">
                                    <property name="STATE" value="message is sent to queue"/>
                                 </log>
                                 <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                                 <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                                 ***<send>
                                    <endpoint key="jmsMBendpoint"/>
                                 </send>***
                                 <header name="To" action="remove"/>
                                 <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                 <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
                                 <payloadFactory>
                                    <format>
                                       <ns1:PostPublicationResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/">
                                          <ns1:MessageID>$1</ns1:MessageID>
                                          <ns1:MessageContent>$2</ns1:MessageContent>
                                       </ns1:PostPublicationResponse>
                                    </format>
                                    <args>
                                       <arg expression="get-property('getMessageIDFromClassMed')"/>
                                       <arg expression="get-property('MessageContent')"/>
                                    </args>
                                 </payloadFactory>
                                 ***<send/>***
                              </then>
                              <else>
                                 <log level="custom">
                                    <property name="InsideNonValidFilter" value="--------State is InValid-------"/>
                                 </log>
                                 <header name="To" action="remove"/>
                                 <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                 <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
                                 <payloadFactory>
                                    <format>
                                       <soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                                          <soapenv:Code>
                                             <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
                                          </soapenv:Code>
                                          <soapenv:Reason>
                                             <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Invalid Parameter</soapenv:Text>
                                          </soapenv:Reason>
                                          <soapenv:Detail/>
                                       </soapenv:Fault>
                                    </format>
                                 </payloadFactory>
                                 <send/>
                              </else>
                           </filter>
```

I have used a filter in my In-Sequence. If the filter is true, then i have to send the payload to Message broker's queue which is defined in my endpoint so i am using a send mediator and after that i have to send the payload as response. But due to use of two send mediator, sometimes i get try-it proxy. How to solve this situation?
One more question? I am passing multiple topic parameter in my topic property. But it is getting only single value
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the response back to client, in the very first send mediator use "receiveSequence" option, where you will receive the response. Inside that sequence, define your other mediation logic..

```
  <send receive="recevingSeq">
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="https://localhost:9445/services/AppService" format="soap11"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
```

Comment: i m not able to send message to queue or show response. Only one happens whatever i provide in my insequence

Comment: if you couldnt send msg to queue, then that is another issue..if you receive response from your endpoint, you will be able to get that in your receivesequence.

Comment: But how? Please provide an example.

Comment: i am able to send to message brokers queue as well as show a custom payloas as response with the above code mentioned in my question but the thing is sometimes it gives me try-it error saying the reason is use of two send mediators.